# Не получается подключиться через FTP к серверу?

Tags: сервер, debian

Уже не первый раз за месяц вылетает такая ошибка и приходится платить сис-админу, чтобы пофиксил её (у него это занимает от силы 10 минут). Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего вылетает эта ошибка? Как по логам на сервере посмотреть в чём проблема?

Сервер: Debian

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: упал ftp сервер или фаервол перекрывает доступ. и это все может быть не случайно....

Comment: упал фтп сервер. Перезагрузил - всё ок стало. Как можно отследить из-за чего произошло падение?

Comment: самый дедовский способ - настроить таску в кроне, которая время от времени будет проверять состояние и перезапускать. Но если дебиан достаточно свежий, то можно systemd задачу поправить так, что бы она сама все делала.